# trigger Update of Account team member

Tags: apex, trigger, account, account-teams

I'm trying to add owner of parent account under team member for child Account.Here is senario.
 Account P with VPA = true and Owner = PO.

·         Account A with VPA = false (or true, doesn’t matter) and Owner = AO.

For Account A, I specify account P as parent account. Then, I expect the trigger to add PO (parent account owner) to the account team of Account A. And again, this should happen only if the parent account has VPA = true.

Here is my work ,which works while creating a new record. I need to extend this by including the update condition i.e if we change the parent owner correspondingly the teAM member has to be changed.

```
trigger AccountTeam on Account (after insert,before update, after update) {
if(trigger.isafter && Trigger.Isinsert  ){
  for(Account acct : trigger.new){

             Integer newcnt=0;
             Integer newcnt0=0;
             AccountTeamMember[] newmembers = new AccountTeamMember[]{};
              //list of new team members to add 
              AccountShare[] newShare = new AccountShare[]{};
               //list of new shares to add 

               list<Account> a1 = [select id,VPA__c, parent.Id,OwnerId from account Where Id=:acct.ParentID];
             for(account acc: a1){
               ID uid =  acc.OwnerId;
                Boolean x=acc.VPA__c;

               //get the user id of the parent Account, if VPA is checked and  will added to the account team
          if( a1.size()>0 && x == True)  {// checking size of list. 
               for(Account a:trigger.new) {           
                        AccountTeamMember Teammemberad=new AccountTeamMember(); 
                        Teammemberad.AccountId=a.id;
                         Teammemberad.UserId=uid; 
                         Teammemberad.TeamMemberRole = 'Global KA Manager'; 
                         newmembers.add(Teammemberad); 
                         } 
                    Database.SaveResult[] lsr = Database.insert(newmembers,false);
                 //insert any valid members then add their share entry if they were successfully added ; 
                 for(Database.SaveResult sr:lsr)
                 { 
                 if(!sr.isSuccess())
                 { 
                 Database.Error emsg =sr.getErrors()[0];

                  system.debug('\n\nERROR ADDING TEAM MEMBER:'+emsg);
                   }
                   else
                   { 
                   newShare.add(new AccountShare(UserOrGroupId=newmembers[newcnt].UserId, AccountId=newmembers[newcnt].Accountid, AccountAccessLevel='Read',OpportunityAccessLevel='Read')); 
                   }
                    newcnt++; 
                    } 
                    Database.SaveResult[] lsr0 =Database.insert(newShare,false);
                     //insert the new shares Integer newcnt0=0; 
                     for(Database.SaveResult sr0:lsr0)
                     { 
                     if(!sr0.isSuccess())
                     { 
                     Database.Error emsg0=sr0.getErrors()[0]; 
                     system.debug('\n\nERROR ADDING SHARING:'+newShare[newcnt0]+'::'+emsg0); } newcnt0++; }
                      }
                          }
                              }

                      }
              }
```

Comment: What did you already try to create the update functionality? It will need to be a trigger on the parent account, and will involve deleting all existing children account teammembers that are no longer needed and creating new teammembers for the new parent account owner.

Comment: in additon to comment:  update trigger has to check whther the parent owner has changed or not. if condition is true then on the child record it has to overwritten the exsiting owner with new one. And this should be done if VPA on Parent is true

Comment: but don't you want to update the child accounts at the moment the parent account owner is updated? Why wait for an update on the child account?

Comment: Yes we have to.while parent get updated parallely child has to be updated.

Comment: You'll probably better off writing a separate trigger for that, since the context is quite different (on parent account instead of child account) and the action is also different (check if owner changed, remove existing sharing rules on children, create new sharing rules on childeren). Let me know if you run into any problems with that.